# IndexedDB - search index event.target.result always null

Tags: html, indexeddb

I can't figure out what's wrong with this snippet of code. I have an indexedDB instance. The keyPath is auto-generated. I can successfully add objects to the DB and get all objects in the DB, but I can't successfully search for an object in an index I created.

See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R5ngM/13/

Comment: I updated the code to confirm that the index "lname" is successfully created: http://jsfiddle.net/R5ngM/16/

Comment: thanks for including a fiddle. i'll take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't nailed it perfectly yet but the issue seems to be that you're opening the cursor on your object store, rather than the index. With the default keyPath that works fine but it won't work when you're trying to use a secondary index.

What I think you're looking to do should look like:

```
    var request = null;
    if ( null === index || 'undefined' === typeof index ) {
        request = transaction.openCursor( keyRange );
    } else {
        request = index.openCursor( keyRange );
    }
    request.onsuccess = on_success;
```

UPDATE: I spent a lot of time looking in the wrong place after finding the above issue with the index cursor. Here's the issue: *The object you're storing is an array not an object literal.*

I was looking into the object you were storing and noticed this:

```
        var entry = '<li>'+row[0].fname+' '+row[0].lname+'</li>';
```

See how you're accessing the first element of the `row` array? You're storing an array. Your keypath (and me) assumed an object was stored. I believe it's possible to have an index on an array but in any case your `keyPath` is off.

[Here's a largely-similar chunk of working code](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/vdeDv/). I mucked it up a bit while debugging but you'll get the gist. (It's a nice snippit so if you don't mind, I'll use it as the base of other StackOverflow examples later on.)

Keep the cursor on the index as explained in my answer above. Then change to this line:

```
var entry = '<li>'+row[0].fname+' '+row[0].lname+'</li>';
```

And the change this:

```
var newUser = [{fname:$('#fname').val(),lname:$('#lname').val()}];
```

To this:

```
var newUser = {fname:$('#fname').val(),lname:$('#lname').val()};
```

Comment: I opened a cursor on the index to try to see the contents, but it's null. http://jsfiddle.net/R5ngM/17/ I wish jsfiddle had line numbers. I guess I just have an empty index...

Comment: None of my attempts are returning a `IDBCursorWithValue` object yet they all return something in `onsuccess` and no `onerror`s. I'm leaning toward the same conclusion but the question is why?

Comment: I just tried the latest version of FF to see if my broswer fixes were bad and FF doesn't seem to recognize any attempt I make to initialize indexedDB even though I'm using examples from mozilla docs. This is lame.

Comment: Your code won't work in FF because it's the Dec 2011 version of the IDB API and not the latest. The difference is that for DB install the former uses a `setVersion` request (what you have) and the latter uses an `onupgradeneeded` callback. Try looking at my WIP library if you're having issues. Library: https://github.com/editor/InDB/blob/master/indb.dev.js Example app skeleton: https://github.com/editor/InDB/blob/master/indbapp.dev.js

Comment: Note that in the event object it's saying `returnValue: true`

Comment: You're awesome. I thought it was weird I could only get the value with row[0].lname not row.lname, but completely missed those extra brackets. Thanks a ton. That code is actually the best example code I've seen yet -- or will be until the specs change again :)

Comment: thanks! i've yet to clean up & package my InDB library, but in the meantime it's a pretty good example and covers most bases. better, i've been building apps on top of it to make sure it works from a developer's perspective and it seems to be teaching me a lot about a) how IDB works and b) when it should be used and not used. in any case, two favors: 1) join the `indexeddb-users@googlegroups.com` group if you can so we can spread the good word and 2) star this chrome issue so we can see their support for the new IDB spec come to pass http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108223

Answer (score 0):

It must also be noted that the above issue can even arise when you open a cursor on the index. If you open the cursor on index and still you always get null you should double check the data type that you created the index on and the the data type on which you're creating your index cursor on. In my case I'd created the index on string data-type and was opening a cursor on the index with int and it was driving me crazy.